# what happens when an event handler is running and another event (same or different event type) happens? (in a socket.io client)

Tags: javascript, socket.io, handler, shared

I have multiple event handlers inside a socket.io client and I want to make sure that none of them would execute if another handler is running.

I don't know what happens when:

The handler of an event named push is running and has not finished, and another event named message happens (or another push happens).

Can their handlers start running before the execution of currently running handler has finished?

If that is possible and we have shared variables how can we control accessing them

Thanks in advance

Comment: A single javascript script is single threaded, and that ensures that two events will be handled entirely sequentially.
I do not know about two scripts.

Comment: Thankyou Maxime. I'm not sure but I guess what you said is true when we use pure javascript or even when we use a single library like angular.js, but I have a code in which an event is broadcasted by angular inside a socket.io event handler, and angular event handler is called before the next line of socket.io handler. Maybe and just maybe every library has it's own event emitting and handling system.